# Autoanswer iOS Funtionality

Tags: ios

I need clarification on the development part.

I was been told to develop an app with an auto answer (call) facility – it’s a critical care app where an ailing father, mother or any other family member can be monitored through auto answer facility (phone call). On the worst case would it be possible through app to app, I mean the auto answering facility. We want this facility to be enabled for our app (for specific numbers) and not for other phone or whatsapp calls.
I’ve tried my research through other forums and connecting with the developers but unable find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to have an app answer an GSM call.

However you can answer a VoIP call yourself when using the VoIP Push from [PushKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit).
In conjunction with [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit), your app could auto answer this call after a timer fires.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion. Can you give me more info regarding this